# почему мой вопрос не поднялся после добавления ответа?

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

почему мой вопрос [Как должны записываться [йэ] и [ййэ] после гласного?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448157/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b9%d1%8d-%d0%b8-%d0%b9%d0%b9%d1%8d-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be) не поднялся на главной после добавления ответа?

я написал ответ сам себе. вероятно, из-за этого.

9:56 : он уже появился. значит, правильный ответ это: скорее всего, главная была закеширована...

Comment: время ответа "6:42z", время вот этого вопроса - "6:55z" и примерно в "6:55z" я увидел что вопрос появился на главной. думаю, кеш главной не обновлялся примерно 5 - 10 минут. через 13 минут я увидел обновление, значение, кеш обновляется не реже чем каждые 13 минут. но, вообще, по-моему, это странно. даже если он обновляется каждые 5 минут, это, по-моему, странновато.